# Is a viewable .git folder a security risk?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Recently started using Git via Bitbucket which is great. However I was a little concerned to be able to view the file tree from any browser?

I do have .gitignore enabled but I assume no file data or commit refs cannot be linked or of use to third parties. The folder permission for `.git/` is `755` by default on my hosting.

Here is what I can see:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5PH24NA.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major risk is if the folder can be downloaded. If it is, anyone can download all the source code.

You can try `git clone http://website.com/.git`. If it's work you have to secure that.

You can have complete information [here](http://www.jamiembrown.com/blog/one-in-every-600-websites-has-git-exposed/) and [there](https://superuser.com/questions/327449/i-left-my-git-directory-readable-by-the-web-server-what-risks-do-i-have)

Comment: Yes, I can see the file tree as above when I access my site in a browser www.website.com/.git.  trying to clone doesn't work though - I have put RedirectMatch 404 /\.git in htaccess. What permissions should the .git folder have?

Comment: Should the .git folder never really be in public_html and could it be moved to / (root) without losing details?